# How to make TextViews unclickable from the java code in Android?

Tags: android

I have a couple of clickable `TextView` items in my app that I want to make unclickable when I click a button. So what code do I write within the button's onClick method?

Comment: Did you tried TextView.setClickable(false); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below

```
 textView.setClickable(false);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

```
public void setClickable (boolean clickable)

Added in API level 1
Enables or disables click events for this view. When a view is clickable it will change its state to "pressed" on every click. Subclasses should set the view clickable to visually react to user's clicks.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
textview.setClickable(false);
```

..............................

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
textView.setClickable(false);
textView.setLinksClickable(false);
```

Inside your `onClick()` method.

Have a look about [setClickable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable%28boolean%29) and [setLinksClickable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLinksClickable%28boolean%29).